# If statement within linq

Tags: linq

Is it possible to include an if statement within this linq query...for example, if viewModel.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara ==null dont use a where clause, simply fetch all records?

```
 viewModel.Courseroot = (from course in container.Courses
                                        where course.Description == viewModel.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara
                                        orderby course.Name descending
                                        select new Course_() { Name = course.Name, Description = course.Description, Guid = course.Guid, CourseID = course.CourseID }).Skip((int)skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `||` operator:

```
viewModel.Courseroot = (from course in container.Courses
                                        where viewModel.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara == null
                                        || course.Description == viewModel.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara
                                        orderby course.Name descending
                                        select new Course_() { Name = course.Name, Description = course.Description, Guid = course.Guid, CourseID = course.CourseID }).Skip((int)skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

Because the `||` operator is short-circuiting, the second part won't be evluated if the first is true.

Or you could construct the query step by step:

```
IEnumerable<Course> query = container.Courses;
if (viewModel.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara != null)
    query = query.Where(course => course.Description == viewModel.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara)
viewModel.Courseroot = query
    .Select(course => new Course_() { Name = course.Name, Description = course.Description, Guid = course.Guid, CourseID = course.CourseID })
    .Skip((int)skip)
    .Take(take)
    .ToList();
```